# hexagon hover show that particular content

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

**[Demo](http://codepen.io/uidesigner/pen/BNMWdx)**

I tried to draw hexagon shape using 6 different colors triangle ..

Every triangle have different content which is same triangle color..

If hover triangle its show only that particular content...

```
<div class="hexagon">
  <div class="triangle" id="top_triangle"><span>Psychological</span></div>
   <div class="triangle" id="top_right_triangle"><span>Cognitive</span></div>

   <div class="triangle" id="bottom_right_triangle"><span>Social</span></div>
   <div class="triangle" id="bottom_triangle"><span>Physical</span></div>
     <div class="triangle" id="bottom_left_triangle"><span>Economic</span></div>
      <div class="triangle" id="top_left_triangle"><span>Emotional & <br>Strengths</span></div>



</div>
```

**Problem here**
Hover not working properly. I think z-index is that problem.
If I hover the pink color (see below images) I need what the picture show.. but my code running show yellow color content.

**I need** any where hover triangle to show that particular Content.

[image]

Comment: @JaromandaX: thank u for reply.. is it work what i need?

Comment: @JaromandaX: i tried SVG to draw... but its also same problem.. hover to show content not correctly...

Comment: @JaromandaX: I tried this [Demo](http://codepen.io/uidesigner/pen/OVdQBK)

Comment: yeah, well you're creating 6 **rectangular** SVG's with triangles in them - try creating one svg with 6 triangles in it